# Why does SBT resolve SNAPSHOT version?

Tags: sbt, nexus, ivy

Here are my resolvers:

```
resolvers in ThisBuild ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" at "https://.../repository/maven-snapshots/",
  "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" at "https://.../repository/maven-releases/")
```

Here is how dependency is specified:

```
libraryDependencies += a %% b % "1.+"
```

Nexus contains `1.0.0` in `maven-releases`

Here is the log I get:

```
[FAILED     ] a#b_2.11;1.0.0-SNAPSHOT!b_2.11.jar:  (0ms)
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/me/.ivy2/local/a/b_2.11/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/b_2.11.jar
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.../b_2.11/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/b_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/me/.sbt/preloaded/a/b_2.11/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/b_2.11.jar
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/pavelvoronin/.sbt/preloaded/.../b_2.11/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/b_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[warn] ==== Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager: tried
[warn]   https://.../repository/maven-snapshots/.../b_2.11/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/b_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[warn] ==== Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager: tried
[warn]   https://.../repository/maven-releases/.../b_2.11/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/b_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Why does it look for `SNAPSHOT`? And does not notice `1.0.0`?

Some lines from Ivy [docs](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html):

> end the revision with a **+** selects the latest sub-revision of the
>   dependency module. For instance,  if the dependency module exists in
>   revision 1.0.3, 1.0.7 and 1.1.2, "1.0.+" will select 1.0.7.

**Update**

After I cleaned Ivy cache it started just telling me that `1.+` is not found. And here are some logs from Nexus:

```
2017-10-18 11:51:07,030+0000 DEBUG [qtp219355933-2530] user org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Router - Request: Request{action=‘HEAD’, path=‘/.../b_2.11/maven-metadata.xml’, parameters={}, payload=HttpRequestPayloadAdapter{contentType=‘null’, size=-1}, multipart=false}

2017-10-18 11:51:07,031+0000 DEBUG [qtp219355933-2530] user org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.BrowseUnsupportedHandler$MatcherImpl - Matching: HEAD /.../b_2.11/maven-metadata.xml

2017-10-18 11:51:07,034+0000 DEBUG [qtp219355933-2530] user org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.Router - Response: Response{status=Status{successful=false, code=404, message=‘.../b_2.11/maven-metadata.xml’}, payload=null}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that your resolvers have same name. sbt should be complaining about it. Does it resolve `1.0.0` if you rename/remove snapshots resolver?

Comment: No, it doesn’t. That was the first I tried. Same result.:( Neither `[1.0,)` nor `integration.latest` work. I also tried publishing bot as Maven and Ivy artifacts - no difference.

Comment: If you remove the snapshot resolver and it still doesn't resolve `1.0.0` (assuming it's correctly published maven-style), this is something strange. I would file it as an issue on [sbt/sbt](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues)

Comment: @laughedelic May be this is something about Nexus because this kind of versioning works fine for public repositories.

Comment: @laughedelic Further investigation revealed that SBT asks Nexus for `maven-metadata.xml` file at `path=‘/.../b_2.11/maven-metadata.xml` and gets `404 - NotFound` in response. Seems like SBT does not generate this file when publishing.

Comment: Shouldn't it be pom.xml? I recommend you to ask in the sbt gitter chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that standard `sbt pack` does not create `maven-metadata.xml` file.

With [Aether-deploy](https://github.com/arktekk/sbt-aether-deploy) plugin everything works fine.